# Possible to count amount of outputs from System.out.println, Java?

Tags: java, output, counter

due to a complex issue which I do not want to enter here, I am not able to count a number of created objects(let's say apples) in a complex Java class, using a simple counter as soon as an apple is created. Therefore I was thinking of an alternativ but do not know how to realize it; if it is at all an option:

A for-loop connected to System.out.println("Apples:" + apples) gives me as many outputs as there are apples. - Which is fine. Now I have to store the number of outputs in a variable - how would you do this - is it possible at all, as the output is displayed in the console?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is really not a good idea, I mean it. But, it is possible to do it globally by creating your own `PrintStream` that will count call to `println` and setting it with `System.setOut`. I'm not going to give any code because I feel it is wrong and that the problem ought to be solved another way: this is typical XY problem.

Comment: I must be missing something. Why can't you simply increment a counter every time you call println?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap `System.out.println()` with your own println method that in addition to printing will count, and use that one instead of println in your loop:

```
private static int counter = 0;

public static void myPrintln(String str) {
  counter++;
  System.out.println(str);
}
```